# Is it possible for a Facebook app to post a "private" Wall post that only the posting user and his/her friend can see?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

An app can post a wall post on a user's behalf.

A user can post a wall post on his own Wall, tag a friend in it, then set it to only be seen by that friend.

Can an app post a wall post on a user's Wall, tag a friend in it, and set it to only be seen by that friend?

Answer (score 2):

**You can done this easily**

change the privacy settings of the Post

object containing the value field and optional friends, networks, allow, deny and description fields.

The value field may specify one of the following strings: EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM .

The friends field must be specified if value is set to CUSTOM and contain one of the following strings: EVERYONE, NETWORKS_FRIENDS (when the object can be seen by networks and friends), FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, ALL_FRIENDS, SOME_FRIENDS, SELF, or NO_FRIENDS (when the object can be seen by a network only).

The networks field may contain a comma-separated list of network IDs that can see the object, or 1 for all of a user's network.

The allow field must be specified when the friends value is set to SOME_FRIENDS and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and friend list IDs that 'can' see the post.

The deny field may be specified if the friends field is set to SOME_FRIENDS and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and friend list IDs that 'cannot' see the post.

The description field may contain a comma-separated lists of valid country, city and language if a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified.

Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page, event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the target's Wall.

Privacy Policy: any non-default privacy setting must be intentionally chosen by the user. You may not set a custom privacy setting unless the user has proactively specified that they want this non-default setting. Note that the visibility of the post will be determined by the more restrictive of the user's privacy setting as well as the post's privacy field

[For more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

***Thanks...***

Answer (score 0):

dont know about tag
but posting on USER's wall(current user)
Post on facebook wall, with Privacy for few friends can be made in this way

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
      'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',));
    $accesstoken=$facebook->getAccessToken();
    //get access token
    $privacy = array(
            'description' => 'any_description_goes_here',
            'value'   => 'CUSTOM',
            'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
            'allow'   => 'YOUR_FRIENDS_ID'
        );
   //define privacy for the post
   //
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $userid ."/feed";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $accesstoken,                        
                        'name'          => "checking",
                        'link'          => "www.google.com",
                        'description'   => 'check',
                        'message'       => 'test',
                        'privacy'       => json_encode($privacy)
                    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    $result= curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
```